# How to redirect to different URL in server component based on if the user is logged in

Tags: next.js, auth0, next.js13

I am trying to redirect the user to '/chat' page if they are already logged in. In Next.js 12 based on the docs, I can use the following code:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getSession(context.req, context.res)

  if (!!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/chat',
        permanent: false,
      },
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {},
  }
}
```

Since I am only using Auth0 for authentication.

However, I get an error stating that it is deprecated in Next13 and it is understandable since we can now use fetch instead. I successfully could use the client side approach to redirect the user:

```js
export default  function Home() {
  const {isLoading, user, error} = useUser();
  const router = useRouter()

  if (isLoading) return <LoadingSkeleton />
  if (error) return <div>{error.message}</div>
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Chatty AI - Login or Sign Up</title>
      </Head>
      <div className='min-h-screen w-full bg-gray-800 flex justify-center items-center text-white text-center'>
        <div>
        {
          !!user && router.push('/chat')
        }
        {
          !user && 
          <>
          <Link href="/api/auth/login" className='rounded-md bg-emerald-500 px-4 py-2 text-white hover:bg-emerald-600'>
          Login
          </Link>
          <Link href="/api/auth/signup" className='rounded-md bg-emerald-500 px-4 py-2 text-white hover:bg-emerald-600'>
          Sign Up
          </Link>
          </>
        }
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

However, I am failing to do it for a server-side component without using 'use client'.

Comment: Maybe that is something that should be done with a middleware instead? https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `redirect`?

```js
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'

export default  function Home() {
    const {isLoading, user, error} = useUser();

    if (!user) {
        redirect('/chat')
    }
    // ...
}
```

The docs mention that this can be used in both server and client components: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect

Comment: Yes I did! Thank you , but I was wondering how can I actually call getSession if I can not use getServerSideProps to retrieve the context parameter?